# Recherche value in other dataframe for computation

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like that:

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = c("C1","C1","C2","C2"),year = c(1998,2001,1998,2001), amount = c(11000,11500,5000,4100))
```

I created another df based on the first one as follow:

```
df2 <- aggregate(amount ~ year, df1, sum)
```

I would to create a new column `df1$ratio` corresponding to the amount ration of each ID for each year. it should look like:

```
df3 <- data.frame(country = c("C1","C1","C2","C2"),year = c(1998,2001,1998,2001), amount = c(11000,11500,5000,4100), ratio = c(.6875, .7372,.3125,.2628))
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two step process, it can be done with `ave` from `base R`

```
df1$ratio <- with(df1, amount/ave(amount, year, FUN = sum))
```

---

Or with `mutate` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate(ratio = amount/sum(amount))
```